# ListPicker shows object name instead of property

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding, listpicker

In my model I have class:

```
public class Heaviness
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string NameToDisplay {get; set;}
}
```

in my view model I have a property HeavinessList:

```
public ObservableCollection<Heaviness> HeavinessList {get;set;}
```

In my xaml I added ListPicker with items source binded to HeavinessList; its data template for item is binded to NameToDisplay property of Heaviness object.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="HeavinessGroup" Width="220" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <TextBlock x:Name="HeavinesLabel" Margin="12,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
               Text="Heaviness:" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="HeavinessListPicker" 
                        SelectedIndex="0"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding HeavinessList}"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NameToDisplay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker>
</StackPanel>
```

However, when I run the app I got the object name displayed instead of property. Why does it happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to assign your `DataTemplate` to the `ItemTemplate` property and don't put it directly into the `ListPicker`:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="HeavinessListPicker" 
                        SelectedIndex="0"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding HeavinessList}"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NameToDisplay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

You can read more about [DataTemplates on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) (the article is about WPF but the same concepts apply for WP7)