# ListPicker shows object name instead of property's value

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listpicker

### XAML:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Name="SourceAccountList" Width="680" FontSize="20" Height="50">
      <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <StackPanel>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding AccountIban}" />
              </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
      </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

### Code:

```
public TransferInternal()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Service1Client WCFClient = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
    WCFClient.GetSourceAccountIntenalListCompleted += new EventHandler<GetSourceAccountIntenalListCompletedEventArgs>(WCFClient_GetSourceAccountIntenalListCompleted);
    WCFClient.GetSourceAccountIntenalListAsync(GlobalVariables.ClientID);
}

void WCFClient_GetSourceAccountIntenalListCompleted(object sender, GetSourceAccountIntenalListCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    List<AccountModel> AccountList = new List<AccountModel>();

    foreach (var ListItem in e.Result)
    {
        AccountModel Account = new AccountModel();
        Account.AccountID = ListItem.AccountID;
        Account.AccountIban = ListItem.AccountIban;
        AccountList.Add(Account);
    }

    SourceAccountList.ItemsSource = AccountList;
}
```

When I try to select something in SourceAccountList it displays object name instead of its properties values. What am doing wrong? I found similar problem

[ListPicker shows object name instead of property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269293/listpicker-shows-object-name-instead-of-property)

But I'm doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to Make the FullModeItemTemplate Like this

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Name="SourceAccountList" Width="680" FontSize="20" Height="50">
      <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <StackPanel>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding AccountIban}" />
              </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
      </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
<toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <StackPanel>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding AccountIban}" />
              </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
      </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

List picker has two kinds of itemTemplate the "normal" that displays when you have when you have less than 5 items  and the "Full Mode" that displays when you have more than 5.

to create a FullModeItemTemplate you should do something like this

```
   <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="30" Text="{Binding AccountIban}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to override the ToString() method in the AccountModel class

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return this.AccountIban;
}
```